# My Taxonomies search is showing page not found error in WordPress

Tags: php, wordpress, custom-post-type, custom-taxonomy

I am working on my WordPress website and I have added the Custom post type plugin for creating the new section and I have also added the taxonomies for that.

In my page, I have added the default categories drop-down select box using the elementor editor but the problem is that, it is not showing the taxonomies added for the Custom post type and also on selecting the taxonomy, it is showing the page not found.

So, I went to the `wp-includes/category-template.php` and edited the file.

```
function wp_dropdown_categories( $args = '' ) {
  $defaults = array(
    'show_option_all'   => '',
    'show_option_none'  => '',
    'orderby'           => 'id',
    'order'             => 'ASC',
    'show_count'        => 0,
    'hide_empty'        => 1,
    'child_of'          => 0,
    'exclude'           => '',
    'echo'              => 1,
    'selected'          => 0,
    'hierarchical'      => 0,
    'name'              => 'cat',
    'id'                => '',
    'class'             => 'postform',
    'depth'             => 0,
    'tab_index'         => 0,
    'taxonomy'          => 'project_type',
    'hide_if_empty'     => false,
    'option_none_value' => -1,
    'value_field'       => 'term_id',
    'required'          => false,
);

$defaults['selected'] = ( is_category() ) ? get_query_var( 'cat' ) : 0;

function wp_list_categories( $args = '' ) {
$defaults = array(
'child_of'            => 0,
'current_category'    => 0,
'depth'               => 0,
'echo'                => 1,
'exclude'             => '',
'exclude_tree'        => '',
'feed'                => '',
'feed_image'          => '',
'feed_type'           => '',
'hide_empty'          => 1,
'hide_title_if_empty' => false,
'hierarchical'        => true,
'order'               => 'ASC',
'orderby'             => 'name',
'separator'           => '<br />',
'show_count'          => 0,
'show_option_all'     => '',
'show_option_none'    => __( 'No categories' ),
'style'               => 'list',
'taxonomy'            => 'project_type',
'title_li'            => __( 'Categories' ),
'use_desc_for_title'  => 1,
);

$r = wp_parse_args( $args, $defaults );
```

In place of `'taxonomy' => 'category'`, I added this `'taxonomy'=> 'project_type'`, Now the taxonomies are showing but the search according to the drop-down select box is not working. It is showing page not found.

Any help is much appreciated.